# How to make a flash file a link (clickable to go to a URL)

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3

I am new to Flash.

I am using Adobe Flash CS3 to create simple animations (images moving between keyframes).
It produces a SWF file that I put on a website.

I want the SWF file to be a link to a URL. How do you do that?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same answer using AS3:
in the 1st frame that the invisible button appears, you should paste the following code:

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, linkToPage);
function linkToPage(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("your page here");
    navigateToURL(request);
}
```

You should name the button instance 'myButton' (in the properties bar - the bottom-left input dialog). That should do the trick.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Bruno and Joel

Answer (score 0):

1st you have to create an invisible button. An invisible button is a button with only the HIT frame. Create a button that covers all your stage. It will appear in your stage as a blue-transparent shape. Just click it and press F9 to bring the 'actions' window.

After that, just paste the following code into the window:

```
on(release){
    getUrl("here you put your url");
}
```

After that, just compile your code as AS2. I think that's the easiest way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I didn't expect having to use AS. Do you know the code for AS3? Because all other projects here are using AS3.